# Django application in heroku

Tags: django, apache, heroku

Can anyone knows how to use these technologies in social networking site?.i had referred a social networking site came to know that they have use these technologies.If you can prepare a flow and main purpose of using it.it will be helpful for me.The technologies iam planning to use are listed below
Thanking you in advance.

- Python 2.7.
- Django 1.3.1.
- Apache  as web-server.
- RabbitMQ as a   message queue.
- Nginx  as mail proxy server.
- HAProxy  for   load-balancing in cloud.
- MySQL  5.1 as database system(Xeround).
- Heroku Paas as cloud service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are approaching this process backwards.  While it's useful to have a general idea of what technologies you want to use for your application when you start, really what you need to do is design your application to fit your needs and your intended use cases and choose appropriate technologies to match.  For that reason, it doesn't make much sense to ask someone to explain the purpose of a technology when you need to be choosing the technology to fit the purpose.

I can't comment on how appropriate these technologies are for your application because "social networking site" describes a huge domain of possible applications.  You need a very specific idea of what you want to do before anyone can give you advice on how you want to do it.

In general Heroku is a fine platform for all manner of web applications, but some of these choices don't make sense for Heroku.  For instance, it does not make sense to use Apache as a web server hooked up to Django in this case.  Cedar, Heroku's new technology stack (and the only Heroku stack to support Django) will work much better with e.g. [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).  There is no technical reason why Apache plus for instance mod_wsgi couldn't possibly work, if you tinkered with the Heroku buildpack to set it up, but it's not the right choice here.

Heroku has [very explicit documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) on how to set up Django with Cedar.  This documentation presupposes you are using Postgres instead of MySQL, which in fact is usually a good idea, but you can easily configure it to use any MySQL service you prefer.  There are affordable MySQL packages included as Heroku add-ons.

For email, by all means use [Heroku add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/).  Do not try to deploy your own mail server on the Heroku stack (while it might technically be possible, again by tinkering with the buildpacks, it's not the point of Heroku).

Load balancing is done automatically by Heroku.  If Heroku's load balancing is insufficient for any reason I recommend you contact support directly, because they have always shown interest in addressing any properly identified shortcomings in their service when I have interacted with them.

RabbitMQ is provided as an add-on for Heroku so you should have no trouble, if you are sure you need this service for your application.

Comment: I have not work with this gunicorn.So can i use the apache as webserver?Can heroku supports tens of thousands of connections simultaneously or i want to use some load balancing technologies please advice?

Comment: for heroku appilcation whether it is necessary  to use membase and memcache/redis for logical-caching or i need to use any HTTP accelerator ?

Comment: gunicorn obviates the need for Apache.  With gunicorn, each Heroku dyno can support a small handful of concurrent requests, and you can scale the number of dynos up basically as far as you want.  If you really scale into the thousands of connections you will have bottlenecks at the database level and you will need to design your application to minimize those issues.  Memcache is one tool to reduce database load.  For static assets such as images, you should serve those from a content delivery network such as Amazon Cloudfront or some manner of Heroku add-on.

Comment: I should probably clarify two things: if you do not design with heavy load in mind, you will experience database bottlenecks far before you reach thousands of concurrent connections.  And if you are really getting thousands of concurrent connections (which would be an extremely high-traffic website) then before you get to that point you should probably have an entire staff of professionals to manage your application either on Heroku or elsewhere.